# Build code: "strlwr" by pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Someone can tell me different between this code:

```
char *s1 ="Con Chim Non";
```

and this one:

```
char *s=new char[100];
gets(s);
```

Then, I add the word: `"Con Chim Non"`.

After, I build a code that change value of the pointer. In first code, I got a problem about the address. The second is right. And this is my code:

```
void Strlwr(char *s)
{
    if (s == NULL )
        return ;
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if ( s[i] <= 'Z' && s[i] >= 'A')
            s[i] = s[i]+32;
    }
}
```

And someone can tell me why the first is wrong.

Comment: The difference is that the first is not valid C++11, nor C++14, and the second is not valid C++14.

Comment: Can you explain clearly for me?. I used the second and got a right result.

Comment: `gets` has been removed from C++. It's a terrible function that does nothing to prevent buffer overruns. Even C didn't want it and got rid of it in C11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example:

```
char *s1 ="Con Chim Non";
```

You declare a *pointer* to a text literal, which is constant. **Text literals cannot be modified.**

The proper syntax is:

```
char const * s1 = "Con Chim Non";
```

Note the `const`.

In your second example, you are declaring, reserving memory for 100 characters in **dynamic** memory:

```
char *s=new char[100];
gets(s);
```

You are then getting an **unknown amount** of characters from the input and placing them into the array.

Since you are programming in the C++ language, you should refrain from this kind of text handling and use the safer `std::string` data type.

For example, the `gets` function will read an unknown amount of characters from the console into an array.  If you declare an array of 4 characters and type in 10, you will have a `buffer overflow`, which is **very bad**.

The `std::string` class will expand as necessary to contain the content.  It will also manage memory reallocation.